# Entities in participate in the relationship. 0 related were found. 1 is expected

Tags: c#, mapping, entity, relationship, state

I'm working on a project for school and I'm having issues mapping a 1-on-1 relationship. It's about a proposal having a certain state (new, accepted, etc), according to the state pattern. The relationship is required on both sides. Here's my code:

for the mapping class of proposal:

```
    namespace Projecten2Groep23.Models.DAL.Mapper
{
    public class ProposalMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Proposal>
    {


        public ProposalMap()
        {
            ToTable("Proposals");



            HasKey(p => p.ProposalId);
            Property(p => p.ProposalId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            Property(p => p.Title);
            Property(p => p.KeyWords);
            Property(p => p.Goal);
            Property(p => p.Plan);
            Property(p => p.Problems);
            Property(p => p.ResearchArea1);
            Property(p => p.ResearchArea2).IsOptional();


            HasRequired(p => p.ProposalState).WithRequiredPrincipal().Map(b=> b.MapKey("ProposalStateMapId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
            //NotMapped weghalen in proposal.cs als je proposalstate wil mappen
            HasOptional(p => p.Feedback).WithRequired().Map(b => b.MapKey("FeedbackMapId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            HasOptional(p => p.CoPromotor).WithRequired().Map(b => b.MapKey("ProposalMapId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        }

    }
}
```

for the mapping class of a proposalstate

```
 namespace Projecten2Groep23.Models.DAL.Mapper
{
    public class ProposalStateMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProposalState>
    {

        public ProposalStateMap()
        {
            ToTable("ProposalState");

            HasKey(p => p.ProposalStateId);
            Property(p => p.ProposalStateId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            HasRequired(p => p.Proposal).WithRequiredDependent().Map(b => b.MapKey("ProposalMapId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);



        }

    }
}
```

Now, when invoking context.SaveChanges I keep getting the exception stated in the title. I've tried virtually every configuration of the relationship, but it still won't get mapped.

I've searched through a dozen posts on stackoverflow, to no avail.

EDIT: Someone asked for the saving operation

```
namespace Projecten2Groep23.Models.DAL
{
    public class BachProefRegistrationInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BachProefRegistratieContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(BachProefRegistratieContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                Student student = new Student("student", "student@student.be", true, "student");
                Proposal proposal = new Proposal("lol", "keywords", "plan", "problems", "research", null, "title", new Copromotor("copromotor", "copromotor@copromotor.be", "organisatie copromotor"), 0, "referencelist", DateTime.Now);
                proposal.ProposalState = new AdviceBPCState(proposal);
                proposal.Feedback = new Feedback();
                student.AddProposal(proposal);
                BPCoordinator bpc = new BPCoordinator("bpc", "bpc@bpc.be", true, "bpc");
                ICollection<Student> students = new List<Student>();
                students.Add(student);
                Promotor promotor = new Promotor("promotor", "promotor@promotor.be", false, "promotor", students);
                Student student2 = new Student("pieter", "p2groep23@gmail.com", false, "pieter");
                List<User> users =  (new User[] {student, bpc, promotor, student2}).ToList();

                context.Proposals.Add(proposal);
                users.ForEach(u => context.Users.Add(u));

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                string s = "Fout creatie database ";
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    s += String.Format("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.GetValidationResult());
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        s += String.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"", ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                throw new Exception(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide code section of save operation?

Comment: Sure, I'll give you the whole shebang

Comment: It's been a while, any update on this?